# 2010 Designer Workflow

Tags: html

I have list A (using advanced settings user sees only items they create) works great - However HR wants the ability to add new users in list B - so I have made a template of List A and turned off advanced settings then create List B and add new field NEWEMP (text field)  HR enters the information for the new employees - how can I use a workflow to take the new item created in List B by HR and using new emp field to populate the Created By in List A.

Answer (score 0):

Use a person/group field instead of a text field in list b and you'll be able to do the mapping in a workflow easier.

You'd do Update item in list A where Created by equals List B NewEmp.

Answer (score 0):

A SharePoint Designer workflow won't be able to update the "Created By" field, so you won't be able to have HR create the items (even via workflow) and still allow the employees to edit only "their" items using the Item-Level Permissions setting in Advanced Settings.

Short of writing a custom event receiver (through which you would be able to set the "Created By" field value using [SPListItem.SystemUpdate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.systemupdate(v=office.14).aspx)), the closest thing you could do is use a People Picker (Person or Group) field instead of a text field, as @PirateEric suggested, then copy that value to a different People Picker field on List A via workflow. You would then need to ensure that the only public view of List A is filtered such that the People Picker field is equal to "[Me]" so that users only see their own items. You will also want to ensure the employees don't have access to create personal views on the list, which may entail setting up a custom permission level.

This approach is considered "security by obscurity" because it doesn't actually restrict employees from viewing or editing other people's items, but it does make them harder to find.

The above approach will only work if the employees have valid accounts in SharePoint at the time HR is entering the information into List B, which may be questionable if the list is tracking something like employee onboarding.